# TIBDataSet.ExecSQL

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I'm new to delphi, and I like it very much, I'm working on a project in delphi 5 and I ran over some code that goes like this:

```
{$DEFINE DB_OTHER}

var aquery: {$IFDEF DB_MSACCESS}TAdoQuery;{$ENDIF}{$IFDEF DB_OTHER}TIBDataset;{$ENDIF}
...
with aquery do begin
  ...
  ExecSQL; <= here is the problem
  ...
end;
```

the code uses two conditional defines, first one works perfectly, but the other one makes the compiler go crazy! it says that "ExecSQL" is a undeclared identifier for some reason...

The code should compile flawlessly, but for some reason, it screams that ExecSQL is not correct, any help is welcomed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You post "the code uses two conditional defines", but there are none in the code you posted. It's not possible to solve the problem if you don't give us the information needed to help you. Please edit your question and provide more information, including the conditionals and where the problem is located. Thanks.

Comment: I edited, can you look again please?

Comment: I don't see an issue, if the define you show at the top is correct. `TIBDataSet` indeed has an `ExecSQL` method, and so that should compile fine. So does `TAdoQuery`. There's something else going on, but with the code you posted it's impossible to tell what it might be, I'm afraid. The very first thing I would do is get rid of the `with`, to make sure you're getting the scope of things right. There's nothing wrong in the small amount of code you're posting, however. I'm doubting it's real code, though. :)

Comment: ahhh, I just looked at the definition of the TIBDATASET, it misses "ExecSQL" procedure, it is there in delphi 7, but not in my version d5 update pack 1, can you please tell me what version of d5 do you have? thanks

Comment: I don't have Delphi 5. I looked at the earliest version of Delphi I have installed (Delphi 7). I think you've found your problem. :)

Comment: yes... but the delphi version is so old and I don't know what to do now, what do I need, from where? :(

Comment: You need a later version of Delphi. It looks like the code was written for Delphi 7. (Do you have the ADO components for Delphi 5, BTW? It wasn't part of the Professional version; you had to buy them separately from Borland. It was included in the higher SKUs, though.)

Comment: We have a D5 Enterprise with update pack 1 and ado components, but I think interbase was updated in some update/fix pack... the problem/question is in which and where can I get that...

Comment: You'd have to see if you can get it from [Embarcadero](http://embarcadero.com/delphi). They own the product now. I don't have any other ideas; Delphi 5 was released more than a decade ago, and is not even supported by most of the third-party component vendors any more.

Comment: Here is an IBX update: http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/17152

Comment: Arjen thank you very much, is it possible that you post that as an answer so I can reward you? this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBX Update download: [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/17152)